# How to find end points of a parallel line?

Tags: geometry

Heres my scenario.. 
I have two parallel lines segments,AB and CD  of equal length.
If A,B are known, how do I find C and D?!

Answer (score 2):

$x_3,y_3$ can be arbitrary. Then let $x_4=x_3+x_2-x_1, y_4=y_3+y_2-y_1$.

If you more specifically want $ABDC$ to be a rectangle, select $t$ arbitrary, then let $x_3=x_1+t(y_2-y_1), y_3=y_1+t(x_1-x_2)$ in the above.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, since there are infinitely many lines parallel to AB.

Comment: sorry! my bad.. the perpendicular distance between the lines is known.. should have mentioned that in the question..

Comment: you want ABCD be a rectangle? On which side of AB you want CD to stay?